# Web app getting zoomed in chrome

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-chrome

I am making a react application. When I open the application in chrome browser, it gets zoomed in. I have to zoom out chrome to 75% to see the actual applicatio. In 100% my application looks all zoomed. Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Check your head section for metatag declaration. Mostly there should be the problem with user-scalable value. It should be 1.0 for perfect result.

Here is the full code for correct meta tag

```html
<!-- For 100% page rendering -->

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- OR
* To lock the zoom of the page -->

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

If its not working well for you, please share your website link to review further.

Comment: I already have meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0") in my layout.jade file

Comment: Please share URL to review

Comment: It is a web app. I can't give the access to it unfortunately. Is there any other way to approach this issue?